# caching - RAM access times

Tags: c++

Consider two loops over an array:

```
int *arr = new int[1024 * 1024];
// Loop1
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) arr[i] *= 3;
// Loop2
for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 16) arr[i] *= 3;
```

As they both are O(n) in big O notation, however, they have the same number of RAM access. i.e. same number of cache misses.

Why would they have the same number of RAM access? Wouldn't loop 2 has less RAM access according to after each visit i is incremented by 16?

Comment: What OS ? What processor ? What compiler ? You asking a specific question without any information. Whatever the answer is probably too complex.

Comment: Hello Stargateur, it is general Computer Science topic specific to c/c++ language, OS would be Unix or Linux ideally. Different machines and hardware shall not affect the answer.

Comment: @JasonLiu Cache details are extremely hardware-specific.

Comment: @Stargateur, you are right. I only got this information thought. Let's make assumption of the cache line size is 64 byte.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cache is always accessed / managed with the granularity of a line. There will be more than one element in a cache line. I think your cache line can hold 16 elements or more and hence one RAM access will load all the adjacent elements to cache and further RAM access is not required for the next 16 bytes.

Comment: Can I think in this way that once a loop require any data access from the array, system will first check if the array is in the cache. If not, then the array will be copied to the cache entirely.

Comment: @JasonLiu not the array, the cache line. lets say the cache line size is 64 bytes, if any read occurs, then that whole 64-byte segment that it is part of is loaded into the cache.